# stray comma with cut paste on notepad++ under wine, ubuntu/gnome

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, notepad++, wine, german

I have ubuntu 16.04 with gnome and a German QWERTZ keyboard. I like notepad++ so installed it under wine. It works very well except for one absurd quirk.

When I delete/copy with "shift"delete" it does indeed copy the selected text into the paste buffer, and delete it but it leaves a , "comma" behind. This nuisance is not enough for me to dump notepad++ but enough to ask advice here.

I'm vaguely aware that notepad++ (probably for no good reason) has its own keyboard settings that even worse can be changed by obscure hot key combinations. Can't find them however.

Anyway my question is how to prevent the stray "comma" being inserted after an otherwise perfect "shift"delete"

Comment: And what happens if you cut using Ctrl+X?

Comment: Interesting. With ctrl-x I have no problem. Any idea what this means?

I have another problem BTW. I've had to disable word suggestion, because often the suggestion box goes full screen. And as I have a 4k monitor it means my np++ taking 1/3 of the screen, and maybe two other applications are obscured by a spelling window suggestion taking the whole monitor!

Comment: It can mean that Shift+Del could be interfering with some shortcut used by Wine or some other application. Just try Shift+Del without selecting anything first. Is it still producing a comma? For you another problem, kindly open a new question. It could collect helpful answers from other users. Please also attach the screenshot, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for cut operation.

You can also check whether <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> has problematic behavior also when there is no selection marked or if you are pressing it in another application etc. It could be colliding with something else running, specific for that environment.